# How do I use a regular expression to match a variable-length number with hyphens in the middle?

Tags: .net, regex

I want a .net regular expression for the following:

The user can enter a value like `tcm:12312312-221231323` or `tcm:23121231-23423423-34234234`

All of the entries except "tcm" and the hyphen will be numeric.  There will be either one or two hyphens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^tcm:\d{8}-(\d{9}|\d{8}-\d{8})$
```

That's either tcm:(eight digits)-(nine digits) or tcm:(eight digits)-(eight digits)-(eight digits)

---

```
^tcm:\d+(-\d+){1,2}$
```

If you're looking for either tcm:(some digits)-(some digits) or tcm:(some digits)-(some digits)-(some digits)

Comment: Hi patrick, its not constant it can be any number in between, minimum it can be tcm:0-0 and max can be tcm:0-0-0

Answer (score 2):

Try this one, which requires two groups or three groups

```
tcm:\d+-\d+(-\d+)?
```

If there are restrictions on the lenht of the numbers, try something like:

```
tcm:\d{4,8}-\d{4,8}(-\d{4,8})?
```

(where 4 and 8 is the minimum and maximum for each group)

Comment: what about tcm:somedigits-somedigits-64?

Comment: @Manoj in that case change the last 4,8 to 2,8 or whatever is necessary

Comment: change the last 4,8 to suit -- the 4 is the minimum number of digits, and 8 is the maximum for a group. Similarly, you could use the first option there, which has at least a single digit in each group, with the last group being optional

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

tcm:[\d-]+

?

Comment: Minimum it should be tcm:2323-32232 and maximum can be tcm:2323-2323-23223, I mean minimum tcm:0-0 and max tcm:0-0-0

Comment: tcm:somedigits-somedigits-64?

Answer (score 0):

Well, a dash in the middle of a number is not numeric... ;)

Here are some options:

If the dashes are optional:

```
^tcm:[\d\-]+$
```

If the dashes are optional, but may not occur first or last:

```
^tcm:\d[\d\-]*\d$
```

If at least one dash is required:

```
^tcm:\d*-[\d\-]+$
```

If at least one dash is required, but may not occur first or last:

```
^tcm:\d+-[\d\-]*\d$
```

If dashes are optional, but may not occur first or last or next to each other:

```
^tcm:\d+(-\d+)*$
```

Comment: tcm:somedigits-somedigits-64?

Answer (score 0):

I's not clear if you want to validate the input and just *match* the input or if you want to extract the data.

If you just need to match the input to validate it, then:

```
 ^tcm:\d+(-\d+){1,2}$
```

Will only match if there are 2 or 3 groups of digits, no less, no more.

If you need to account for whitespace that may occur, you could modify the Regex like this:

```
 ^tcm\s*:\s*\d+\s*(-\s*\d+){1,2}\s*$
```

If you wanted to extract each set of digits:

- In Perl, you would use the `@result` array that would contain 2 or 3 groups of digits only if the whole pattern matched (the `subject` string contains the line you want to extract data from).

  ```
  my @result = $subject =~ /^tcm:(\d+)-(\d+)(?:-(\d+))?$/;
  ```
- In C# you could do the equivalent thing:

  ```
  MatchCollection results = null;
  Regex r = new Regex(@"^tcm:(\d+)-(\d+)(?:-(\d+))?$");
  results = r.Matches(subject);
  if ((results.Count == 2) || ((results.Count == 3))) {
      // use results.Item[] to access each group of digits
  } else {
      // The subject doesn't match
  }
  ```